# MySQL AB, MySQL Server 5.5 Folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE not present

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to MySQL for Python (MySQLdb package) in Windows so that I can use it in the Django web frame.

I have just installed MySQL Community Server 5.5.9 and I have managed to run it and test it using the testing procedures suggested in the MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual. However, I discovered that I still don't have the MySQL AB folder, the subsequent MySQL Server 5.5 folder and regkey in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, which is needed to build the MySQLdb package.

From the MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual, it says that:

> The MySQL Installation Wizard creates one Windows registry key in a typical install situation, located in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB.

However, I do have the Start Menu short cut and all the program files installed. I have used the msi installation and installed without problems. Should I be getting the MySQL AB folder? Does anyone know what has happened and how I should get the MySQL AB/MySQL Server 5.5 folder and the regkey?

Comment: I suggest you put that in an answer, since I couldn't find it either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the key was actually generated under HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Thanks.